# Is there a way to sync Dynamics CRM contacts to surveymonkey?

Tags: api, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, surveymonkey

Is there a way to sync Dynamics CRM contacts to surveymonkey? I would like to find a syncing app which can automatically import all my Dynamics CRM contacts to Surveymonkey. It would make my workflow much easier, instead of uploading CSV files... Any ideas? Someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Automate would be a good solution for what you're looking to achieve.
Power Automate will effectively let you integrate practically any service that uses an API using a concept of connectors. survey monkey has a connector for power Automate, however you may have to create a custom connector to perform bulk data uploads - I checked the survey monkey connector and it does not have a lot of actions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/surveymonkey/#actions

Your Power Automate flow can be created to run on a daily basis to move data between dynamics and Survey Monkey